# How to find whether a site uses SET

Tags: encryption, protocols

How could I know whether the eCommerce site I use uses [SET (Secure Electronic Transaction)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Electronic_Transaction). I know SET is a standard. But I see only an SSL connection

Answer (score 3):

> I know SET is a standard

As Avid pointed out, the SET standard was abandoned in favor of the [3-D Secure scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-D_Secure); so no, it isn't really a standard. If I recall correctly, the protocol never really gained wide-acceptance due to its complexity and cost versus simply using SSL.

> How could I know whether the eCommerce site I use uses SET?

The chances that your ecommerce store use SET are very low (<1%). However, there is a simple way you can check to see if the ecommerce store uses SET... if you need to install an "e-wallet" client-side application, then you can rest assured you are using SET. However, not having to install the client-app won't tell you much because SET can be implemented on the backend server, in which case the problem of having to use an e-wallet is offloaded to the server in a way that is transparent to the user.

In the end, there isn't a 100% accurate way to tell whether or not you are using SET, but I think it's a moot point given its lack of acceptance or use.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Electronic_Transaction) (emphasis mine):

> Secure Electronic Transaction (SET) **was** a standard protocol for securing credit card transactions over insecure networks, specifically, the Internet. SET was not itself a payment system, but rather a set of security protocols and formats that enable users to employ the existing credit card payment infrastructure on an open network in a secure fashion. **However, it failed to gain traction. VISA now promotes the 3-D Secure scheme**.

So, no, that site most probably is *not* using SET. And apparently, it shouldn't be.